# Multiple Linear Regression with constraints that should satisfy a curve

Tags: multiple-regression, constraint

I would like to estimate a multiple linear regression model with 15 coefficients like this:
            Y=a1x1+a2x2+a3x3+.....+a15x15+e

I have a set of data that include Y(29x1) and X(29x15). I want to find out 15 coefficients that satisfy the experimental graph (in the image) so I want to put some constraints like : 8 coefficients from a1 to a8 should be negative and distribute like the curve in the image and 7 coefficients from a9 to a15 should fluctuate around 0.

Is there any way to do this?? Please help me, I got stuck with this for a long time :(

[image]